# Method ToString() on object adds a backslash to escape characters

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I don't understand what happends in my code.

I have a `WrapPanel` which contains some `RadioButton`. I use the `Tag` property to associate the `Content` property of RadioButton with a real character : e.g. *Tabulation* = *\t*.

This is the XAML part :

```
<WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,24,0,21" Name="wpColSep" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="286" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="58">
    <RadioButton Content="Tabulation" Height="16" Name="rbTab" Padding="6,0,20,0" Margin="0,0,0,7" Tag="\t" />
    <RadioButton Content="Espace" Height="16" Name="rbSpace" Padding="6,0,20,0" Margin="0,0,0,7" Tag=" " />
    <RadioButton Content="Point-virgule" Height="16" Name="rbPointVirgule" Padding="6,0,20,0" Margin="0,0,0,7" Tag=";" />
    <RadioButton Content="Virgule" Height="16" Name="rbVirgule" Margin="0,7,0,0" Padding="6,0,20,0" Tag="," />
    <RadioButton Content="Autre :" Height="16" Name="rbAutre" Margin="0,7,0,0" Padding="6,0,20,0" />
    <TextBox Height="23" Name="tbAutre" Width="41" Margin="0,10,0,0" Padding="6,0,20,0" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Then, I try to get the checked `RadioButton` and save the character in `Tag` with this code :

```
var rbChecked = wpColSep.ChildrenOfType<RadioButton>().Where(c => c.IsChecked ?? false).FirstOrDefault();
if (rbChecked == rbAutre && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbAutre.Text))
{
    //Not important here
}
else if (rbChecked != null)
{
    ConfigImport.SeparateurColonne = rbChecked.Tag.ToString();
}
else
{
    //No RadioButton checked
}
```

This works perfectly, but when `Tag` = "\t", `rbChecked.Tag.ToString()` produces "\\t".

What is the reason for this and how can I avoid this ?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: How do you verify this, are you looking at the result in the debugger? The debugger, when inspecting string variables, will escape certain characters, but that is a visual thing, the string does not necessarily contain those characters. If you're verifying this some other way, please tells us how.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, I put a breakpoint after these lines and I look at the value of `ConfigImport.SeparateurColonne`.

Comment: Then this is not an issue. This is the debugger, not the actual string contents.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. When I display the string with a MessageBox for example, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking at the result in the debugger.

C# has to escape some characters with `\`, like `\t`, `\r` and `\"`. You will see that escaped string in the debugger console. Don't worry, the actual string is fine. Click on the magnifier next to the variable and you will see the actual value.

The 'wrong' value (which is the same as `string abc = "abc\\n"`):

[image]

Looks okay:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you ! Indeed with the Text Visualizer it works fine. The next little thing is that when I try to show `ConfigImport.SeparateurColonne` in a `MessageBox`, it literally prints `\t`. How to not considerer this string as a *string literal* ?

Comment: What is `ConfigImport.SeparateurColonne`? What is the value of `rbChecked.Tag`? How is it filled?

Comment: As you can see in my code, it is filled like that : `ConfigImport.SeparateurColonne = rbChecked.Tag.ToString();`. In the Text Visualizer it shows a real tabulation, but in a `MessageBox` it show *\t*. The strange thing is that `MessageBox.Show("\t")` show a real tab.

Comment: @Chostakovitch : in the code there is the literal `\t`. Note it is XAML, not C#. Try placing there a real tab. (maybe you have to copy one from notepad or so).